# Get Window 8 Start Screen tiles

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-8

I would like to get a listing of all the tiles on the Win8 Start screen.  I do not need them to live update just get the appropriate tiles/icons.
What is the way to get all the tiles found on the Windows 8 Start Screen?

**Clarification:**

What I am looking for is images of the tiles pinned to the start screen (not just my application's).  I would like to provide those images to the user in a different way.

In Windows 7 I would just gather everything from the start menu folder and then gather their icons.

I recognize that I cannot create a Windows Store app to do this.  I was planning on this being a desktop app.

Comment: Are you talking about secondary tiles of your apps or all other apps' tiles i.e. music, mail, skydrive, etc. ?

Comment: Updated to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Store Apps (aka Metro apps) are installed in "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps"

Your app idea is impossible as WinRT app because WinRT app has sandbox nature, so you can't access that path. If you want to develop desktop app then it's possible.

In that folder, you will find separate folder for each app. Look for "Assets" or "images" folder. It contains all the logo (Wide, Store, Small, SplashScreen, etc) of particular app. **The folder name may differ for any app, "Assets" & "images" is default folders.**

*You also may need to visit [this](https://superuser.com/questions/498768/where-to-find-windows-8-modern-ui-apps-source-code/498771#498771)*

Comment: Also buried in your link was this http://justinangel.net/ReverseEngineerWin8Apps

It seems to point out why doing this potentially could open security holes.

I was really looking for something to do this API-wise.  IF you are saying that isn't an option then I will accept this answer.